# Backbone model from JSON file appearing as attribute

Tags: json, backbone.js, model

I am trying to determine what the issue is here. Basically, I am loading a file with JSON content into a backbone.js collection. It is properly locating the file, loading the content, and I can see (through the browser developer tools) that one of the 12 JSON objects is accessible, but it is missing the other 11 objects and it appears that the one that is loaded is being classified as an 'attribute'. I am somewhat new to backbone.js and I an not sure what I have done wrong. Code and screenshots below:

Code I am using to load JSON content from the file:

```
var cmd = Backbone.Model.extend({});
var cmdList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: cmd
});
var myCmds = new cmdList();

myCmds.fetch({
    add: true,
    url: "CustomFiles/Commands.txt",
    success: function () {
        console.log("JSON file load was successful", myCmds);
        $.each(myCmds, function (key, value) {
            console.log(key + ": " + value.Description);
        });
    },
    error: function () {
        console.log("There was some error in loading and processing the JSON file");
    }
});
```

Here is an abbreviated version of the Commands.txt file that contains the JSON content:

```
{
"Command": {
    "build": 1,
    "TouchedBy": "corpUser1",
    "TouchedWhenUTC": "2013-10-24 06:58:15.5130000 +00:00",
    "CreatedBy": "corpUser1",
    "CreatedWhenUTC": "2013-10-24 06:58:15.5130000 +00:00",
    "Active": "TRUE",
    "MSRowversion": "",
    "id": 1,
    "Name": "Start Services",
    "Description": "To start all Services",
    "Type": 1,
    "Data": ""
},
"Command": {
    "build": 1,
    "TouchedBy": "corpUser1",
    "TouchedWhenUTC": "2013-10-24 06:58:15.5170000 +00:00",
    "CreatedBy": "corpUser1",
    "CreatedWhenUTC": "2013-10-24 06:58:15.5170000 +00:00",
    "Active": "TRUE",
    "MSRowversion": "",
    "id": 2,
    "Name": "Stop Services",
    "Description": "To stop all Services",
    "Type": 2,
    "Data": ""
},
[9 other JSON objects (commands) - formatted exactly the same way...],
"Command": {
    "build": 1,
    "TouchedBy": "corpUser2",
    "TouchedWhenUTC": "2014-10-30 08:48:37.0770000 +00:00",
    "CreatedBy": "corpUser2",
    "CreatedWhenUTC": "2014-10-30 08:48:37.0770000 +00:00",
    "Active": "TRUE",
    "MSRowversion": "",
    "id": 28,
    "Name": "Stop Services T",
    "Description": "To stop all Services for T",
    "Type": 2,
    "Data": ""
}
}
```

My JSON content appears to be correct, but as you can see from the screenshot(s) of the developer tools, it is loading, but it is not loading all of the objects and I cannot access the value of the 'Description' attribute of the 'Command' object.

[image: Unable to access 'Description' attribute of the 'Command' object]

In the following screenshot, you can see that only one command has loaded and it is identified as an attribute. Am I over-analyzing/over-complicating this or is there something simple I am overlooking?

[image: 'Command' object loaded as an attribute and missing the other 11 objects]

What can I do to properly load and iterate over these JSON objects?

---

**UPDATE:**

I modified the Commands.txt file so that the "Command" key was no longer present and altered the opening and closing brackets so that the objects would be part of an array. So, I went from this:

```
{
    "Command": {
        "build": 1,
        "TouchedBy": "corpUser1",
        "TouchedWhenUTC": "2013-10-24 06:58:15.5130000 +00:00",
        "CreatedBy": "corpUser1", 
        "CreatedWhenUTC": "2013-10-24 06:58:15.5130000 +00:00",
        "Active": "TRUE",
        "MSRowversion": "",
        "id": 1,
        "Name": "Start Services",
        "Description": "To start all Services",
        "Type": 1,
        "Data": ""
    },
    "Command": {
        "build": 1,
        "TouchedBy": "corpUser1",
        "TouchedWhenUTC": "2013-10-24 06:58:15.5170000 +00:00",
        "CreatedBy": "corpUser1",
        "CreatedWhenUTC": "2013-10-24 06:58:15.5170000 +00:00",
        "Active": "TRUE",
        "MSRowversion": "",
        "id": 2,
        "Name": "Stop Services",
        "Description": "To stop all Services",
        "Type": 2,
        "Data": ""
    },
    [9 other JSON objects (commands) - formatted exactly the same way...],
    "Command": {
        "build": 1,
        "TouchedBy": "corpUser2",
        "TouchedWhenUTC": "2014-10-30 08:48:37.0770000 +00:00",
        "CreatedBy": "corpUser2",
        "CreatedWhenUTC": "2014-10-30 08:48:37.0770000 +00:00",
        "Active": "TRUE",
        "MSRowversion": "",
        "id": 28,
        "Name": "Stop Services T",
        "Description": "To stop all Services for T",
        "Type": 2,
        "Data": ""
    }
}
```

to this:

```
[{
    "build": 1,
    "TouchedBy": "corpUser1",
    "TouchedWhenUTC": "2013-10-24 06:58:15.5130000 +00:00",
    "CreatedBy": "corpUser1",
    "CreatedWhenUTC": "2013-10-24 06:58:15.5130000 +00:00",
    "Active": "TRUE",
    "MSRowversion": "",
    "id": 1,
    "Name": "Start Services",
    "Description": "To start all Services",
    "Type": 1,
    "Data": ""
},
{
    "build": 1,
    "TouchedBy": "corpUser1",
    "TouchedWhenUTC": "2013-10-24 06:58:15.5170000 +00:00",
    "CreatedBy": "corpUser1",
    "CreatedWhenUTC": "2013-10-24 06:58:15.5170000 +00:00",
    "Active": "TRUE",
    "MSRowversion": "",
    "id": 2,
    "Name": "Stop Services",
    "Description": "To stop all Services",
    "Type": 2,
    "Data": ""
},
[9 other JSON objects (commands) - formatted exactly the same way...],
{
    "build": 1,
    "TouchedBy": "corpUser2",
    "TouchedWhenUTC": "2014-10-30 08:48:37.0770000 +00:00",
    "CreatedBy": "corpUser2",
    "CreatedWhenUTC": "2014-10-30 08:48:37.0770000 +00:00",
    "Active": "TRUE",
    "MSRowversion": "",
    "id": 28,
    "Name": "Stop Services T",
    "Description": "To stop all Services for T",
    "Type": 2,
    "Data": ""
}]
```

That fixed the majority of my problem. I still have an issue accessing one of the attribute values of the command, but I will do the work to try and figure that part out and come back with a new question if I need to.

Comment: You need to fix whatever broken tool is generating `Commands.txt` so that it generates JSON, an array of objects would be appropriate. Either that or write your own parser.

Comment: Thank you for posting as your comment would have helped me if I had not arrived at that conclusion (an array of objects) on my own. Might help someone else get there quicker...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have three keys with the same name (`Command`) within your object.  Each key will override the last key which explains why only one nested object is ever loaded.

Comment: Your answer solved about 95% of my problem. I am more familiar with XML and started transitioning to JSON recently, so the format didn't look all that unusual to me, but once you mentioned it, I recognized the issue. I posted additional content detailing what I did to correct the additional pieces.